# Easier way to create URL paths

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm quite new to the web-development scene, but I know for sure that I'm still using old/inefficient methods. I need to create URL-Paths like: `domain.tld/path/to/file1` -- I create those paths by just creating folders after the root folder.

**Example:**
Root-folder\Path\to\file1\index.php

**Extra information:**
Those indexes include `<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/parts/content/placeholder.php"; ?>` -- Which checks to the URL to show to correct content.

My question is, is there an easier way to (virtually) create those paths? Maybe using the `.htaccess` or something like that?

Comment: It's really unclear what your objective is here.

Comment: I just try to create virtual paths, so ``domain.tld/path/to/file1`` is defined virtually. But I don't know how or if it is possible.

Comment: The easiest way is a framework that handles this for you, like Laravel.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, indeed. I'll also try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up upon the [Rewrite Module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

With Rewrite, you can use one [`index.php`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) [for all urls](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) or any number of combinations.